# How to find the external IP?

Tags: openshift

I have a Python application which has been deployed to openshift.

I am using an external REST service in my application. In order to use this service, the developers of the REST service have to whitelist my IP because a Firewall blocks unauthorized IP addresses.

How can I find the external IP of my application? How can I find it in openshift? I tried a few OC commands, but I am not sure if I have to get the IP of the pod or the service.

Comment: You may want to look at using a static egress IP if needing all outbound traffic to have a set IP. https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/how-enable-static-egress-ip-red-hat-openshift-container-platform

Answer (score 3):

Out of the box the traffic from internal cluster components will appear to external infrastructure like they are coming from whichever OpenShift compute host their pods are currently scheduled on.

Information on internal cluster networking and how traffic traverses from a process running inside a pod to the external network can be found at [SDN: Packet Flow](https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/networking/sdn.html#sdn-packet-flow).

In your case you could have the external application whitelist all of the ip addresses of the compute hosts that are expected to run your application pods.

Alternately you could set up an EgressIP. This will cause all traffic originating from a specific OpenShift project to appear as if it is originating from a single ip address. You could then have your external application whitelist the EgressIP address.

Documentation for configuring EgressIP can be found in the official documentation under [Enabling Static IPs for External Project Traffic](https://docs.okd.io/latest/admin_guide/managing_networking.html#enabling-static-ips-for-external-project-traffic)

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is the external IP of the Service. A Service acts as a load balancer for your pods but by default it only has a cluster-wide IP address. If you need a URL to access it from the outside, you can create a Route. For your purpose where you need an actual external IP address, you can assign the Service an external IP manually. Information on how to do this can be found in the official [OpenShift Docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_service.html#manually-assign-ip-service).